# How do you generalize the Laplace transform to more variables?

Tags: functional-analysis, laplace-transform

Just what the title says.  How can I take the Laplace transform of $f(x,y,z)$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multivariable version of Laplacian transformation, assume $t=(t_1,t_2,t_3)$, $X=(x,y,z)$, then
$\mathcal L\{f(x,y,z)\}=\int e^{t\cdot X}f(X)$.